# What #:~:text= do in url?

Tags: url, uri

I noticed that google can highlight exact sentences at search results after clicking a link. After a short research I found out that browser highlights some text at page if there are `#:~:text=your_text` in url.

For example, a phrase "search results" will be highlighted if you click this link (in new tab) - [What #:~:text= do in url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62426302/what-text-do-in-url#:~:text=search%20results)

I want to read more info about this, but googling #:~:text= doesn't help. Can you explain how it works and give a link to a specification please?